# Java regex pattern upper case

Tags: java, regex

I want to match string "A SENTENCE OF UPPER CASE" made of at least 3 characters
i've tried

```
[A-Z\s]+{3,}
```

but it also matches strings like "A " "AB"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `+`, which means "1 or more" when you are also putting `{3, }` which means "3 or more". This will confuse the RegEx engine and is likely your problem.

The regular expression should be `[A-Z\s]{3,}`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to match string "A SENTENCE OF UPPER CASE" made of at least 3 characters

By your code with `\s` I am assuming you want to also ignore white spaces between them. So, seems this is the regex you are looking for:

```
([A-Z]\s*){3,}
```

Just remember to capture the `group 0` (all matches) from the capturing groups generated. Also, test it as you wish on this online regex engine:

1. https://regex101.com/r/F29oFj/1

> but it also matches strings like "A " "AB"

This does not make sense as your regex expression `[A-Z\s]+{3,}` is broken because `+` operator cannot be qualified with the `{3,}` operator, i.e., it does not even should compile, so I do not see how the Java regex engine could generated those matches.